# How to send variables to PHP from Android to do a SELECT ... WHERE in PHP

Tags: java, android

I already got a method to read data from mysql and display it into my android app in textview's. The problem is that now I just retrieve all data from the database without doing a select ... where , just a select. I want to do a select ... where using the variables sent from my android app.  I already use the folowing code in my login to send username and pass

`nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("utilizator",utilizator.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parola",parola.getText().toString().trim()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));`

In the method I use I have 2 java files. I really don't understand them much ... so I don't know where to add the code to send variables to php.

httprequest.java

```
public class httprequest {
    static int TIMEOUT = 5000;

    public String read_url_resource(String _s_url)
    {
        String          s_response_ = "";
        BufferedReader br_reader=null;
        StringBuilder   sb_builder = new StringBuilder();

        URL u_url = null;
        try {
            if ( _s_url==null || _s_url.length()==0)
                return "";

            //this.log_message("Downloading from "+_s_url, false);
            u_url = new URL(_s_url);

            HttpURLConnection huc_urlConnection = null;


            huc_urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)u_url.openConnection();

            if ( huc_urlConnection!=null){
                huc_urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
                huc_urlConnection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
                huc_urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                huc_urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
                InputStream is_input_stream = huc_urlConnection.getInputStream();
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                URL oURL = huc_urlConnection.getURL();

                int i_response_code=huc_urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                if ( i_response_code==200){
                    br_reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is_input_stream));

                    String line="";
                    while ((line = br_reader.readLine()) != null)
                        sb_builder.append(line);


                    is_input_stream.close();
                    s_response_ = sb_builder.toString();

                    String s_auth= huc_urlConnection.getURL().getAuthority();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if ( e!=null )
                Log.e("URL PROBLEM", e.toString());
            s_response_ = "[\"error\": \"No connection\"]";
        }

        return s_response_;
    }
}
```

and ReadJSONData.java

```
public class ReadJSONData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

    private String server = "http://asociatia-online.esy.es/cote.php?hc_location=ufi";
    private ReadJSONListener jsonListener;
    private String json ="";
    private int internal_categ;
    httprequest request;

    public interface ReadJSONListener
    {
        void onTaskFinished(String s_json, int _i_internal_category);
    }

    public ReadJSONData (ReadJSONListener _jsonListener, int _i_internal_category)
    {
        this.jsonListener=_jsonListener;
        this.internal_categ =_i_internal_category;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {
        request = new httprequest();
        this.downloadResource();
        return null;
    }

    private void downloadResource() {
        switch (this.internal_categ) {
            case 1:
                this.json = request.read_url_resource(server);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
    {
        this.jsonListener.onTaskFinished(this.json, this.internal_categ);
    }
}
```

So, where to add the 4 lines code to send variables? In which file and where. Thanks !

Comment: You need to add them in "httprequest" class

Comment: if you have solved it ,  paste the solution and accept your self. If might help others in future cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code you can send variables to PHP and get some data back and store it in strings to use as you want.

```
private class ObtinereInformatii extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            //http post
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://asociatia-online.esy.es/rezumat.php");
                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("luna_rezumat",spinner_luna.getSelectedItem().toString().trim()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("an_rezumat",spinner_an.getSelectedItem().toString().trim()));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            }
//convert response to string
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

                String line = "0";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.e("-------",result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){

                try{
                jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                readJson(jArray);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private void readJson(JSONArray ja_data) throws JSONException {
        if (ja_data!=null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<ja_data.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jo = ja_data.getJSONObject(i);
                if (jo.has("data_rezumat"))
                {
                    if (jo.getString("data_rezumat")!=null)
                    {
                        z_data_rezumat= jo.getString("data_rezumat");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```